# how to change timestamp column order in python?

Tags: python

I would like to change the order of the column but the column name is time stamp.
How can I change the order of timestamp column?

Here is the example of data I've got.
It is in data frame and the package I am using is `pandas` and `numpy`

```
properties  2020-11-28 03:00:00  2020-12-26 02:00:00 2020-12-12 01:00:00
 Percent        76.5                     77.62                 71.89
 Power          718.828                  717.949               718.828
```

I've used below query to change the order of the column but I've got error message saying

> Key Error:'value not in index'

```
total_top4 = tot_top4[['THING DESCRIPTION','2020-11-28 03:00:00', '2020-12-12 01:00:00','2020-12-26 02:00:00']]
total_top4
```

Can someone please tell me how to change timestamp format column order?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and include information about what modules you are using and how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set the df using the columns attribute.
I am assuming total_top4 is your dataframe.

```
total_top4.columns=['THING DESCRIPTION','2020-11-28 03:00:00', '2020-12-12 01:00:00','2020-12-26 02:00:00']
```

Please try and let me know if this helps you! Thanks